# equal heights for different labels in one row

Tags: swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have 3 labels in a row they may have different number of words so each one may have different number of lines. I want at the end the height of views become the same. what should I do?

Comment: I put each label in a view (side by side) and add equal width and equal height and also connect them with each other. and for labels connect top and sides to view and left the bottom free

Comment: “become the same” That’s too vague. Become the same as what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the Equal Heights constraint among your 3 labels.  Below is an example.  I have 3 labels in the same view, with the "lines" property of each label set to 0.  Each has a top, leading, and width constraint applied (width = 100).  So each label automatically grows taller as more text is added to them.

[image]

Now simply select all three labels and apply the Equal Heights constraint. Now two of the labels grow in height to match the third label.  Now adding even more text to the label that has the most text will cause the other two labels to match its growing height.  You can prove this directly within Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: But you are getting a warning from Xcode. What does it say?

Comment: I just forgot the trailing constraint on the third label, which doesn't affect my answer.  I've now updated the screenshot after adding that constraint.